# Delete Visible Rows in a sheet that has hidden columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that works fine on sheets that have no hidden columns, whereas this sheet does have hidden columns. I want to delete all visible rows, including the information that is in the hidden columns.

```
TempBook.Sheets("Item Level Detail").Activate

Set rng2 = Range("A1:AO500000")
    rng2.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>" & DistNo, Operator:=xlAnd

ActiveSheet.Range("A2:AO500000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
TempBook.Sheets("Item Level Detail").AutoFilter.ShowAllData
```

I get the error "**cannot use that command on overlapping selections**" because all visible rows have hidden columns.

The visible rows change frequently throughout this code, this is one step within the loop I have.

How can I delete all visible rows without getting the error and without hard-coding in which rows to delete?

Answer (score 0):

The hidden columns are causing `SpecialCells` to return the cells in separated areas. For example if column D was hidden, Column A:C and columns E:AO would be two areas. Then when using `EntireRow`, each area is expanding into the same rows. For example, A1 and E1 are both becoming 1:1. This is why you're having the overlap error.

To avoid the overlap from other sections, limit the search for visible cells to a single column like "A2:A500000" instead of "A2:AO500000".